# How to diagnose why one-tap popup not showing in production

Tags: google-signin, google-one-tap

I added google one-tap to our web app, tested it well working at localhost (see pic).

After deploying to production (react optimized code), the one-tap dialog doesn't show up, checking network traffic, seems some of the requests are missing compared to localhost, but not sure how to diagnose what the root cause is, any help?

*(note: I have tried production URL in incognito mode and restarted my browser)*

**Localhost: (http://localhost:3000)**
[image]

**Production (https://columns.ai)**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if it's related to the OAuth scope, but I added the `opened` and `profile` scopes, and it's now working in production. However, I can't verify if this is what fixed it.